# How to keep displaying character when button is pressed(Embedded C)

Tags: c, arm, embedded

Characters will be displayed on the display LCD of my microcontroller. When I press the user button on the microcontroller, I want the character that is being shown, to keep showing on the LCD until I let go. When I let go, it needs to continue showing the rest of the characters. I know that I have to use an if-statement, but what do I put inside the if statement to keep showing the character that is being shown on the LCD?

```
while (1) {
    p = stringToDisplay;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        LCD_GLASS_WriteChar((uint8_t*) p,POINT_OFF,COLUMN_OFF,1);
        Delay(THREE_MORSE_UNITS);
        LED_ShowMorse(CHAR_TO_MORSE_CODE(*p));
        if ((GPIOA->IDR & USER_GPIO_PIN) != 0x0)
            {
            //code to keep showing the character when the user button is pressed
            }
        p++;
    }
    LCD_GLASS_Clear();
    Delay(FOUR_MORSE_UNITS);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered threading the LED?

Comment: Change the `if` in your `GPIOA->...` line to a `while` to have the MCU busy-wait while the button is pressed. That should keep the LCD from being overwritten. For proper code, however, you will want to de-bounce the button input.